# How can I perform a npm run test in a lerna exec command?

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, unix, lerna

how to execute a npm run test if the condition is true?
please check the code below thanks.

```
lerna exec --concurrency 1 --scope=file --  pwd | awk '{ if ($0 ~ /pattern_match/) {npm run test} }'

$0 = file directories.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
lerna exec --concurrency 1 --scope=file --  pwd | grep '<pattern match>' && npm run test
```

Demo :

```
$echo asd  |  grep [0-9] && echo "Yes" 
$echo 123  |  grep [0-9] && echo "Yes" 
123
Yes
$
```